# C++ Classes with android

Tags: c++, android, class, android-ndk

The android NDK supports c++, but does it support c++ classes??
If so can you give a simple example and the steps needed to implement the class with the java source.

Answer (score 0):

> **The android NDK supports c++, but does it support c++ classes??**

Yes. It supports C++ classes. Classes are fundamental in the language, and the support for classes is implicit when they state that they support C++.

> **If so can you give a simple example and the steps needed to implement it.**

Not sure what you mean by this. Implement what? Implement classes in C++ or implement C++ applications for Android?

Comment: They do support c++. "The NDK allows you to implement parts of your applications using native-code languages such as C and C++" - http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: How would you expect them to support C++ without supporting classes??

Comment: C++ libarys and its not as easy as just creating a c++ application because when you use c with the ndk it needs special names and parameters.